# I have made a react native app that uses a search bar but it is not displayed for android

Tags: android, react-native, react-android

This search bar works just fine for ios and android . Here is the link to the search bar that I am using.
https://github.com/localz/react-native-searchbar
Although it does not show for android but for ios.

Answer (score 0):

After reading their [docs](https://github.com/localz/react-native-searchbar/blob/master/README.md)

**Notes for Android**

**Render the search bar component after the component it is supposed to display over.** iOS handles this nicely with a zIndex of 10. Android elevation is set to 2.
The bottom of the search bar will have a thin border instead of a shadow.

I just used their [example](https://github.com/localz/react-native-searchbar/blob/master/example/example.js) with only adding one line at top

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

and it is working fine